# Nested zip's causing return value of Observable to misfit

Tags: java, system.reactive, rx-java

I'm pretty new to Reactive programming, and have this method which doesn't compile and I can't get it right,

```
public Observable<Data> findData(long templateId) {
    ..
    ..

    return Observable.zip(templateObs, dataObs, (templateObj, dataObj) -> {

        try {

            switch(model) {

                case SINGLE: {
                        ..
                        ..

                        return new Data();
                }


                case TOURNAMENT: {

                        // compilation error on the entire .zip block :
                        // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Observable<Object> to Observable<Data>

                        return Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, obs3, obs4, (data, data2, data3, data4) -> { 
                            ..
                            ..

                            return new Data(data1,data2,data3,data4);
                        }).flatMap(results -> results);
                }
            }

        }catch(DataException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }

        return null;
    });
}
```

For some reason the inner return .zip return Observable instead of Observable - this causes the compilation error...

If I remove the 'return' from the inner .zip then it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` need a lambda which return an `Object`, in your case a `Data`, which is what you've done in the `SINGLE` case.

In the `TOURNAMENT` you return an Observable which is not a `Data` object.

Depending of your case, if you want to return an `Data` then you'll have to block your neested `zip` operator with `toBlocking` method.

```
case TOURNAMENT: 
        return Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, obs3, obs4, 
                             (data, data2, data3, data4) -> 
                                   { return new Data(data1,data2,data3,data4); }
                             ).toBlocking().single();
```

Otherwise, you can return instead of a `Data` object an `Observable<Data>`. In this case, just change your `SINGLE` case to return an `Observable` which will emit only your `Data` object.

```
 case SINGLE:  return Observable.just(new Data());
```

Comment: By using the .toBlocking method does it affect my asynchronous flow or causes and performance issue like blocking the thread?

Comment: yeap. As it's named : `toBlocking` block. As you comment, you may try the second solution which is to return `Observable<Data>` instead of `Data`.

Comment: yeap. `Observable.zip(...).flatMap(obs -> obs)`

Comment: I tried adding: Observable.zip(...).flatMap(obs -> { return obs; }); but it doesn't do the trick - it still doesn't compile with same error. Error = "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Data to Observable<? extends Object>"

Comment: Is your nested `zip` can only return new `Data` ? Don't you have a line which return something else that force the compiler to infere the return type as `Object` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74432/discussion-between-shvalb-and-dwursteisen).